# Xcode Error: This scheme has been created for the “(null)” target. What does "(null)" target mean?

Tags: ios, xcode

I've been working on an iOS project in Xcode and have recently encountered a perplexing issue. Whenever I try to build or run my project, I receive the following message:

> Activate “MyMonitor” scheme?
> This scheme has been created for the “(null)” target. Choose Activate to use this scheme for building and debugging. Schemes can be chosen in the toolbar or Product menu.

I'm trying to understand a few things about this error:

1. What exactly does the "(null)" target refer to? Is it a placeholder for a missing target or is it something else?
2. Could this "(null)" target be the reason my code doesn't seem to be connecting properly to my app extension?
3. How can I correct this issue, so I can continue building and debugging my project without any hitches?

I've been recently adding a new app extension to my project, so I suspect that might be related to the error.
I've tried to clean the build folder, reset Xcode, and even manually edited the .xcodeproj file (based on some suggestions from other questions) but none seemed to have helped.

Comment: Any luck so far?